# Get value of all checkbox selected in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the next Datatable

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Iden.</th>
      <th>Nombres</th>
      <th>Sel.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Iden.</th>
      <th>Nombres</th>
      <th>Sel.</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    scrollX: true,
    deferRender: true,
    "aaData": data.Data,
    "columns": [{ data: "ID" },
                { data: "Identificacion" },
                { data: "Nombres" },
                { "data"      : null,
                  "targets"   : -1,
                  "orderable" : false,
                  "className" : "all",
                  "width"     : "20px",
                  "render"    : function(data, type, full) {
                                  let texto = "";
                                  texto = '<input type="checkbox" id="check_test" value="' + data.ID + '" />';
                                  return texto;
                              }
                }
               ]
});
```

I want get value of the selected checkboxes, so i tried this

```
var aux = [];

aux = $('#example tbody input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
      }).get();
```

however, this only obtains the values selected from the active page of the pagination datatable

**How can I get the value of the selected checkboxes on all pages of datable?**

Comment: Can you also share your paginated html output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) DataTables API method to retrieve data from all pages, not just first page.

For example:

```
var $checkboxes = $('#example').DataTable().$('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```